# Functions inside a loop behaves differently

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, clisp

So I have a loop to just repeat the little text game I have made about dota, but when the function 'play' is called within a loop it doesn't return the result of my cond function, it just takes an input and then moves on to the next loop.

```
;;;;learn the invoker combo's
(defparameter *invoker-combo* '((cold-snap  (3 0 0) 'QQQ);all of the possible invoker combo's
                                (ghost-walk (2 1 0) 'QQW)
                                (Ice-Wall (2 0 1) 'QQE)
                                (EMP (0 3 0) 'WWW)
                                (Tornado (1 2 0) 'QWW)
                                (Alacrity (0 2 1) 'WWE)
                                (Sun-Strike (0 0 3) 'EEE)
                                (Forge-Spirit (1 0 2) 'QEE)
                                (Chaos-Meteor (0 1 2) 'WEE)
                                (Deafening-Blast (1 1 1) 'QWE)))
(defun rand-combo (invoker-combo);returns a random combo
    (nth (random (length invoker-combo))invoker-combo))

(defun count-letters (input);converts the keyboard strokes into numbers to be compared as it doesn't matter what order they are in, just that there is the correct quantity of them e.g QQE could also be written QEQ.
    (append
        (list (count #\Q input)
              (count #\W input)
              (count #\E input))))

(defun try-for-combo (rand-combo);takes i-p and compares it with the value for the random combo
    (print(car rand-combo))
    (let* ((i-p (string-upcase(read-line)))
            (try (count-letters i-p)))
            (cond ((equal try (cadr rand-combo))'Good-job)
                  ((equal i-p "END")(list 'Thanks 'for 'playing))
                  (t (list i-p 'was 'wrong 'correct 'is (caddr(assoc (car rand-combo)*invoker-combo*)))))))

(defun play ()
    (try-for-combo (rand-combo *invoker-combo*)))

(defun loop-play (x)
    (loop for i from 0 to x
        :do (play)))
```

If I call the function 'play' I get the following o/p:

```
FORGE-SPIRIT asdf
("ASDF" WAS WRONG CORRECT IS 'QEE)
```

or

```
ALACRITY wwe
GOOD-JOB
```

But if I call the function 'loop-play' I get the following o/p:

```
Break 3 [7]> (loop-play 2)    
SUN-STRIKE eee    
ALACRITY wwe
TORNADO qww
NIL
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening?
EDIT: feel free to change the title, I didn't really know what to put.

Comment: you might want to indent and format your code better.

Comment: If you see a prompt like `BREAK 3 [7]>`, then your Lisp interaction is in a debugger. Get it out of the debugger. Use the command `help` to get help with the available commands. `quit` gets Lisp back to the top level.

Comment: Alrighty thanks. Do you have any links to how to format my code properly, because this is how it's done in the book I'm reading, I've also posted questions about it and everyone is pretty hostile about it so I don't bother.

Comment: Well I looked at the book I'm working through at there were only small things that have made little aesthetic or practical difference, and some whitespace.

Comment: @Floofk Consider using making the invoker-combo variable in rand-combo optional and defaulting to *invoker-combo*. Also using an alist for *invoker-combo*, removing the 3rd column as it redundant. One can translate the list representation to the 'human-readable' one with a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `try-for-combo` function doesn't actually *output* anything. Rather, it *returns* values.

In the REPL, if you evaluate a form, like `(+ 1 2)`, it will always print the evaluation of that form at the end (in this case, `3`). However, consider instead `(+ 1 (print 2))`. The `print` function actually outputs the argument to standard output, then returns the value itself. So this will show (on the repl)

```
2
3
```

The `2` is outputted first, because `(print 2)` itself prints `2`. Then, the form `(+ 1 (print 2))` is evaluates to the same things as `(+ 1 2)`, or `3`.

In your case, your `try-for-combo` function should look like:

```
(defun try-for-combo (rand-combo)
  (print (car rand-combo))
  (let* ((i-p (string-upcase(read-line)))
         (try (count-letters i-p)))
    (print
     (cond
       ((equal try (cadr rand-combo)) 'Good-job)
       ((equal i-p "END") (list 'Thanks 'for 'playing))
       (t (list i-p 'was 'wrong 'correct 'is (caddr(assoc (car rand-combo) *invoker-combo*))))))
    nil))
```

This will print the result of that `cond` form, and return 'nil'.

Comment: In summary use print :D

Answer (score 2):

The indentation and formatting of the code is poor. Please make it easier for you and for us to read the code.

```
(defun try-for-combo (rand-combo);takes i-p and compares it with the value for the random combo
    (print(car rand-combo))
    (let* ((i-p (string-upcase(read-line)))
            (try (count-letters i-p)))
            (cond ((equal try (cadr rand-combo))'Good-job)  ; wrong indent level
                  ((equal i-p "END")(list 'Thanks 'for 'playing))
                  (t (list i-p 'was 'wrong 'correct 'is (caddr(assoc (car rand-combo)*invoker-combo*)))))))
```

- lacks spaces between s-expressions
- wrong indentation levels
- structure of the code unclear
- does not use built-in documentation features
- some lines are too long

Better:

```
(defun try-for-combo (rand-combo)
  "takes i-p and compares it with the value for the random combo" ; built in doc
  (print (car rand-combo))
  (let* ((i-p (string-upcase (read-line)))
         (try (count-letters i-p)))
    (cond ((equal try (cadr rand-combo))                          ; indentation
           'Good-job)
          ((equal i-p "END")
           (list 'Thanks 'for 'playing))
          (t
           (list i-p 'was 'wrong 'correct 'is                     ; several lines
                 (caddr (assoc (car rand-combo)
                               *invoker-combo*)))))))
```

I would propose to use an editor which actually understands some Lisp formatting. like GNU Emacs / SLIME, Clozure CL's Hemlock, LispWorks' editor...

If you are unsure about formatting, you can also ask Lisp to do it. Clisp is not that good at formatting, but something like SBCL or CCL would do:

```
* (let ((*print-case* :downcase))
  (pprint '(defun try-for-combo (rand-combo)
 (print (car rand-combo))
                    (let* ((i-p (string-upcase (read-line)))
 (try (count-letters i-p)))
                            (cond ((equal try (cadr rand-combo))
 'Good-job) ((equal i-p "END")
                              (list 'Thanks 'for 'playing))
 (t (list i-p 'was 'wrong 'correct 'is
                                      (caddr (assoc (car rand-combo)
 *invoker-combo*)))))))))
```

And you get nicely formatted code:

```
(defun try-for-combo (rand-combo)
  (print (car rand-combo))
  (let* ((i-p (string-upcase (read-line))) (try (count-letters i-p)))
    (cond ((equal try (cadr rand-combo)) 'good-job)
          ((equal i-p "END") (list 'thanks 'for 'playing))
          (t
           (list i-p 'was 'wrong 'correct 'is
                 (caddr (assoc (car rand-combo) *invoker-combo*)))))))
```

Automatic indenting of Lisp code by the editor saves you a lot of work.

There are hints for [manual indentation](http://dept-info.labri.fr/~idurand/enseignement/lst-info/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I appreciate it. are there any little ways to remember the correct indentation and formatting? Like a phrase or something. I don't use Emacs because when I first started out it was very confusing having to remember how to use Emacs and some basic lisp as well, so when I changed books I just use Notepad++ as now I can focus purely on learning the LISP not LISP and Emacs.

Comment: @Floofk: Using Notepad++ means that you need to focus on indenting your code manually and other things. Emacs does that for you, which greatly simplifies Lisp programming. Learn Emacs (or any other Lisp aware editor) and it pays back immediately.

Comment: You've sold it to me haha, I'll get emacs and slime :)

Answer (score 1):

That's just the difference between the output your program does and the output the Lisp system does for each evaluation:

`print` prints something (a newline and then its argument) and returns a value. The value is printed by the REPL. Thus we see output twice:

```
[3]> (print "3")

"3" 
"3"
```

Next we do several call to `print` in a `progn`. The value of the `progn` form is printed by the REPL. The first three strings are printed by the code and the last string is printed because of the Lisp REPL printing the value:

```
[4]> (progn (print "1") (print "2") (print "3"))

"1" 
"2" 
"3" 
"3"
```